# Handling the model-update-server response in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

The Backbone.js model updates itself - and its views - locally on the page before
passing the data to the server and checking the server's response, so if the
server says "sorry charlie that's no good" the page has already shown the data
as having changed and thus doesn't correctly represent the server-side state of the object.  What's the correct/elegant way to handle this on the Backbone.js side when the server returns an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about passing success, error callback functions to the statement where you update the server side state. May be something like this....

```
this.model.save(
    {}, {
    success: function() {
        /* update the view now */
    },
    error: function() {
        /* handle the error code here */
    }
});
```

Taking it a level higher, you might override the Backbone.sync to globally handle the server-side error codes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are directly editing a model and trying to sync it, and also using it elsewhere in your app simultaneously, then that can lead to a world of problems.

In many cases it is better to clone the model for editing, and then when it syncs successfully, apply the clone's attributes back on to the original model.

You can get a cloned model by simply calling:

```
var clonedModel = originalModel.clone();
```

And then you can apply the attributes back in a success handler like

```
originalModel.set(clonedModel.attributes)
```

Comment: thanks @maxl0rd, but cloning the model appears to also clone the hooks to the view, so as soon as i update the clone all the views update too, putting me right back where i started.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by hooks. A cloned model has the same attributes as the original, but none of the original's event bindings. However, if your initializer is what is creating the bindings, then those will get created again on the clone. To avoid this, you want the views to bind to the original model only. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
model.save({wait: true});
```

Source: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save